# i accidentally send usdt-trc20 into the usdt-trc20 contract itself... is there any way i could get it back?

Tags: network, usdt

In tron network, I have mistakenly send USDT token to the USDT contract (TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t). Is there anyway I could get my fund back? Thanks!

Comment: I sadly doubt it, you can try to contact the owner of that contract and see if they "CAN" and "would" resend your token back (but don't expect a response :( )

Comment: I have the same problem damn KU coin has the contract address under everything listed. The exchanges don’t want to know and I don’t think there is a route out for the code of usdt I put in . Expensive lesson, I feel your pain x

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [USDT contract you mention](https://tronscan.org/#/contract/TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t/code) hasn't got a function that would allow doing so (the only transfer that would be possible for the contract would be using transferFrom, but that would need the contract to approve an eoa, which is not implemented neither).